# jQuery click event for dynamically added tr's in table with specific ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a click event for all rows in a tbody with a specific id.

I tried this code:

```
$('#availableApps > tr').click(function (e) {
    console.log('hej');
});
```

However this does not trigger any clicks on tr's in `<tbody id="availableApps">`

What am i doing wrong?

HTML, i populate the table dynamically:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="availableApps">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for binding handlers to dynamically added elements.

```
$('#availableApps').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    console.log('hej');
});
```